# Есть ли необходимость в написании ряда вопросов/ответ по pattern matching python

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Никак не успокоюсь по поводу `pattern matching` и все больше и больше открываю возможности данной конструкции, вижу больше возможностей для применения и внедрения в собственный код.

Вопрос состоит в необходимости освещать данные изыскания здесь. Вопросы будут односложные и короткие для раскрытия только одной темы внутри конструкции

Примеры вопросов:

1. Pattern matching Python. Что такое `guard` и его применение
2. Pattern matching Python. Шаблоны и классы
3. Pattern matching Python. Шаблоны с позициононными аргументами
4. Pattern matching Python. Поддпаттерны и ключевое слово `as`

и тд

Comment: если вопрос удовлетворят правилам - его можно задавать

Comment: @Grundy я больше про нужность, правила мы чтим, но не всегда попадаем в аудиторию. Плюс односложные вопросы частенько попадают в очередь проверки как низкое качество, а там как повезет. Некоторые не ценят теоретические вопросы

Comment: как правило. к само-ответам лояльнее отношение

Comment: @Dmitry, будучи очарованным возможностями pattern matching вы отдаете себе отчет о принципиальных проблемах тестирования подобных конструкций?

Comment: @avp пока еще нет, тоже тема для разбора

Comment: @Dmitry, тогда точно начинайте свою серию. Возможно там возникнет полезная для всех дискуссия

Comment: Мне кажется это больше тянет на серию статей (на Хабре, например), чем на серию вопросов-ответов.

Comment: @insolor хабр имеет уже описание основных характеристик и я прихожу к выводу, что конструкция сыровата и не оптимизирована. При более глубоком рассмотрении и накапливании информации (например, [критика PEP622](https://github.com/markshannon/pep622-critique)), приходит понимание, что если конструкция не станет удобной и популярной, и к ее оптимизации не прикоснутся в будущем, то и не зачем тратить на нее время. Хотя на первый взгляд, было многообещающе